# Show grid in Papyrus class diagram

Tags: uml, papyrus

I am looking for a **grid / raster** in Papyrus Neon, so I am able to align the components in my UML class diagram more precisely.

Is there such an option available? If so, where do I find it?

e.g. in ArgoUML such a grid is shown by default:

[image]

My research with Google was not successful either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to find properties like that is to use the search box at the top of the Properties drop-down menu. Type "grid" in there ant you will see that you can set diagrams that support grids an set your desired grid for each. Note tha the way to do this will change change slightly with Papyrus Oxygen, but the capability will remain.

Note that in the diagrams's toolbar, there are also actions to align model element representations (vertically/horizontally/spaced equally) or to make there sizes the same.